# Razor doesn't recognize List()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, generic-list

My View begins like this:

```
@using MyNamespace.Models.Mapping
@{
    PlacemarkKmlModel pmodel = new PlacemarkKmlModel();
    pmodel.Center.Latitude = 8.52115M;
    pmodel.Center.Longitude = -80.35981667M;
    pmodel.KmlObjectTokens kmlIDs = new List<string>();
    pmodel.KmlObjectTokens.Add("Sample1.kml");
    pmodel.KmlObjectTokens.Add("Sample2.kml");
}
@Html.Partial("_Mapping", @pmodel, @ViewData)
```

And Intellisense is giving me a red underline in the 3rd pmodel statement "The type or namespace 'pmodel' could not be found":

```
pmodel.KmlObjectTokens kmlIDs = new List<string>();
```

That is strange because it doesn't give the error in the PlacemarkKmlModel pmodel declaration nor in the use of the same in the statements following that where it even does autocompletion of KmlObjectTokens but it craps out on the 3rd?!.

When I execute the view I get the same error:

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'pmodel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The error is misleading in the sense that it complains about pmodel but what it doesn't seem to like is the List().

My model looks like this:

```
public class PlacemarkKmlModel
{
    public ViewportCenterModel Center { get; set; }

    public List<string> KmlObjectTokens { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
@using MyNamespace.Models.Mapping
@{
    PlacemarkKmlModel pmodel = new PlacemarkKmlModel();
    pmodel.Center.Latitude = 8.52115M;
    pmodel.Center.Longitude = -80.35981667M;
    pmodel.KmlObjectTokens = new List<string>();
    pmodel.KmlObjectTokens.Add("Sample1.kml");
    pmodel.KmlObjectTokens.Add("Sample2.kml");
}
@Html.Partial("_Mapping", pmodel, ViewData)
```

Notice that in your code you had `@(` instead of `@{` to open the code snippet.

Also notice that the following is invalid C#:

```
pmodel.KmlObjectTokens kmlIDs = new List<string>();
```

I guess you wanted to simply assign the `KmlObjectTokens` property on the `pmodel` instance in which case the correct syntax is:

```
pmodel.KmlObjectTokens = new List<string>();
```

And a final remark : views are not intended to contain C# code and initialize models. That's the responsibility of the controller. I am afraid that you have mixed up the responsibilities in the MVC pattern.

Comment: +1 for the last remark regarding the MVC pattern responsibilities

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the fact that razor treats < string > as an HTML tag like this:

1. Create a helper class where you have a factory of string lists:

   ```
    public class Helpers
    {
       public static List<string> GetNewStringList()
       {
           return new List<string>();
       }
    }
   ```
2. Use that factory in the razor view to create a new list of strings:

   @pmodel.KmlObjectTokens = Helpers.GetNewStringList();

But, as Darin said, you should not mix responsibilities in the MVC pattern, so the model should already contain your KmlObjectTokens list populated with the data.